# Beagleboard doesn't show up welcome screen at the first boot

Tags: beagleboard

I bought a Beagleboard xm. It comes with a micro SD card containing a demo program. I connected Hdmi to dvi converter and the monitor. I was supposing to see a welcomescreen when I connect the power cable. But nothing appears on the screen and the monitor goes to sleep.

How should I proceed?

Comment: Do you have the console output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There can be quite a number of things that might have gone wrong. A faulty SD card, a faulty board, some left-over u-boot build in NAND flash, etc.

Your best bet at diagnosing the problem is via the serial console. To access the console, you'll need to build a serial cable - there isn't one included AFAIK. For the details of the cable, check out [BeagleBoard System Reference Manual](http://beagleboard.org/static/BBSRM_latest.pdf).